# AVR External Interrupts Triggering in Assembly

Tags: assembly, arduino, interrupt, avr, interrupt-handling

I would like to change Arduino Nano (ATMega328p) led pin (13 - PB5) state by triggering an External Interrupt (using pin INT0 - PD2) in AVR Assembly Code.

I am using Atmel's avrasm2 assembler to compile to .hex file. The code is:

```
.list               
.org 0x0000
    rjmp main
.org 0x0002 
    rjmp INT0_ISR       
.org INT_VECTORS_SIZE
.def dreg = r18
main:           
    cli                
    ldi r17, LOW(RAMEND)
    out SPL, r17
    ldi r17, HIGH(RAMEND)
    out SPH, r17            ; set Stack Pointer
    sbi DDRB, 0x05          ; set PINB5 as output (Pin 13)
    sbi PORTB, 0x05         ; set PINB5
    cbi DDRD, 0x02          ; set PIND2 as input
    cbi PORTD, 0x02
    ldi r16, 0x01           ; enable external interrupts
    sts EIMSK, r16
    ldi r16, 0x05           ; change triggers
    sts EICRA, r16
    ldi r16, 0x20
    sei    
loop:          
    rjmp loop
INT0_ISR:    
    push r17
    in r17, SREG            ; push status register to SP
    com r16
    out PORTB, r16          ; negate PORTB (PINB5)
    out SREG, r17           ; restore status register
    pop r17            
    reti                    ; return from ISR (INT0)
```

Trying the code both in Atmel Studio's Simulator and Microcontroller the INT0 External Interrupt is not triggering. Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Note: the bouncing effect is solved due to hardware solution, don't mind about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used wrong instruction to save value to EIMSK. EIMSK isn't memory mapped.
You should use out instruction

```
    out EIMSK, r16
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! But using out or sts didn't make any effect, EIMSK register on simulator keeps having its expected behavior, but the stack pointer is not jumping to ISR no matter the instruction...

Comment: It is another issue. In AVR studio is flag **Mask interrupts while stepping**. You should set flag to false. You can find this flag in the **Tools** menu, **Options...** item, then **Tools**.

Comment: Thanks, buddy!!! That was it, you are great!